# Error: expected unqualified-id before & token

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I'm very new to C++ and I am creating my first class. I have every error out of the way except one:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before & token
```

The assignment operator signature looks like this:

```
Job::& operator = (const Job &v )
```

I've tried everything I can think of, removing the &, doing Job::Job & operator, removing the Job. Nothing works.

I know it's simple, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When declaring inside the class definition:

```
Job& operator = (const Job &v )
```

When defining outside the class definition:

```
Job& Job::operator = (const Job &v )
```